# <a> tag appending href to current url instead of linking directly to what is inside of the href

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

Inside a Vue component there is content that is pulled from firebase and  imported into a table so it can be displayed. One of those "fields" so to speak is url. In the database it is structured as {name:"my link",url:"www.example.com"} and is put directly into an  tags href. When that component loads and I inspect the  tag it says that hrefs value is "www.example.com" but when I click the link it goes to "currentURL/www.example.com" Below I have included the  tag in question. It is a part of a  tag where for each field in that particular content type there is logic that decides what type the field is

```
<a v-else-if="findFieldType(field.name) === 'url'" :href="filteredContent[index][field.name].link">{{ filteredContent[index][field.name].name }}</a>
```

The  tag is supposed to link to what is in its href attribute("www.example.com"), not to append the value from href to the current url and link to that("myCurrentUrl/www.example.com").

This behaviour is expected when using vue-router since this its  role, to append the provided value to the current url so I tried searching for a fix there butr to no avail. That is why I used an  tag, to make sure that vue-router is not going to mess with my links and clicking on that link will lead directly to what is in the href.

Comment: We could prune this question down to "`<a href="www.example.com">Link!</a>` doesn't work", which probably makes it a dupe.

Comment: Despite this being a pretty silly problem (don't worry, it happens to the best of us), it's well-worded and formatted. Good first question!

Comment: Thanks @SIGSTACKFAULT, I know it was something silly and I could have simplified it a lot but the more info the better, you never know what small detail could make or break someone from understanding what the issue is.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [syntax of a URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3):

> The following are two example URIs and their component parts:
>
> ```
>      foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>      \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>       |           |            |            |        |
>    scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
>       |   _____________________|__
>      / \ /                        \
>      urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
> ```

`www.example.com` does not begin with either a scheme or the `//` that would make it relative to the current scheme.

It is, therefore, a URL **relative to the current path**.

**Add the scheme** (or `//`) e.g. `http://www.example.com`.